# Text manipulation using lapply()

Tags: r, dataframe, text, lapply

## Question

Are there other ways I may use `lapply()` to paste the column name  for each element within each column in a data frame?

## Problem

At the moment, I'm resorting to re-using `lapply()` for each column.

## Reproducible Example

```
# create data
df <- data.frame(
  Chicago_Has = c("Lou Malnati's", "Wrigley Field", "CTA" )
  , Seattle_Has = c("Piroshky Piroshky", "Safeco Field", "KCMT" )
  , stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# paste column name into each element 
# within each column
df[ "Chicago_Has" ] <- lapply( X = df[ "Chicago_Has" ]
                               , FUN = function(i) paste( "Chicago_Has", i, sep = " " )
                               )
df[ "Seattle_Has" ] <- lapply( X = df[ "Seattle_Has" ]
                               , FUN = function(i) paste( "Seattle_Has", i, sep = " ")
)

# examine the desired result of the data frame
df

#                 Chicago_Has                   Seattle_Has
# 1 Chicago_Has Lou Malnati's Seattle_Has Piroshky Piroshky
# 2 Chicago_Has Wrigley Field      Seattle_Has Safeco Field
# 3           Chicago_Has CTA              Seattle_Has KCMT
```

## Thoughts

At the moment, I think this method involves too much copying and pasting. If I store `colnames( df )` as a character vector, I don't know how I would use that object - while only using `lapply()` once - to obtain my desired results. I think it involves using multiple counters in the function I'm supplying in `FUN`, but am unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df[]=Map(paste,names(df),df)
df
                Chicago_Has                   Seattle_Has
1 Chicago_Has Lou Malnati's Seattle_Has Piroshky Piroshky
2 Chicago_Has Wrigley Field      Seattle_Has Safeco Field
3           Chicago_Has CTA              Seattle_Has KCMT
```

Comment: After reading the documentation for [`base::Map()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/funprog.html), it appears using [`mapply()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/mapply.html) will give me the exact same result as well.

`df[] <- mapply( FUN = paste, colnames( df ), df)`

Answer (score 4):

Just to complete,  an option with `lapply` where we `paste` , `name` of each column to the individual column value.

```
df[] <- lapply(names(df), function(x) paste(x, df[[x]]))
df

#                Chicago_Has                   Seattle_Has
#1 Chicago_Has Lou Malnati's Seattle_Has Piroshky Piroshky
#2 Chicago_Has Wrigley Field      Seattle_Has Safeco Field
#3           Chicago_Has CTA              Seattle_Has KCMT
```

Comment: Ah you put the column names of `df` as the value for X, then paste each element within X to each element within x column in `df`. This is awesome - thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `map2_dfr` from the [purrr](/questions/tagged/purrr) package to iterate through each column of the `df` and its column name and paste to the element in each column.

```
library(purrr)

df2 <- map2_dfc(df, names(df), ~paste(.y, .x, sep = " "))
df2
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   Chicago_Has               Seattle_Has                  
#   <chr>                     <chr>                        
# 1 Chicago_Has Lou Malnati's Seattle_Has Piroshky Piroshky
# 2 Chicago_Has Wrigley Field Seattle_Has Safeco Field     
# 3 Chicago_Has CTA           Seattle_Has KCMT
```

Comment: I believe its the same concept only that this is `map` in `purr`

Comment: @Onyambu Yes, thanks for sharing your solution. I was not familiar with the base R `Map` function.

Comment: Sure. its perfectly fine.

Comment: @www Thank you for the explanation! I haven't explored the `purrr` package yet so I appreciate the introduction.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `lapply` to get your desired output, because the `paste` function is already vectorized:

```
df$Chicago_Has <- paste("Chicago_Has", df$Chicago_Has)
df
                Chicago_Has       Seattle_Has
1 Chicago_Has Lou Malnati's Piroshky Piroshky
2 Chicago_Has Wrigley Field      Safeco Field
3           Chicago_Has CTA              KCMT
```

### Demo

Comment: You're right, Tim! But the data frame I'm working with has more than 2 columns, which is why I wanted to avoid using the `paste` function on its own. It would require me to copy and paste the `paste` function for however many columns the data frame contains.